# How to omit begin table in stargazer output

Tags: r, output, latex, stargazer

```
library(stargazer)

stargazer(mtcars)
```

I want to omit the table setup part so instead of:

```
% Table created by StarGazer v.3.0.1 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: Thu, May 09, 2013 - 16:14:28

\begin{table}[htb] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\footnotesize 

\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}l c c c c c } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Max} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
mpg & 32 & 20.091 & 6.027 & 10.400 & 33.900 \\ 
cyl & 32 & 6.188 & 1.786 & 4 & 8 \\ 
disp & 32 & 230.722 & 123.939 & 71.100 & 472.000 \\ 
hp & 32 & 146.688 & 68.563 & 52 & 335 \\ 
drat & 32 & 3.597 & 0.535 & 2.760 & 4.930 \\ 
wt & 32 & 3.217 & 0.978 & 1.513 & 5.424 \\ 
qsec & 32 & 17.849 & 1.787 & 14.500 & 22.900 \\ 
vs & 32 & 0.438 & 0.504 & 0 & 1 \\ 
am & 32 & 0.406 & 0.499 & 0 & 1 \\ 
gear & 32 & 3.688 & 0.738 & 3 & 5 \\ 
carb & 32 & 2.812 & 1.615 & 1 & 8 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\normalsize 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

I get instead:

```
% Table created by StarGazer v.3.0.1 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: Thu, May 09, 2013 - 16:14:28

\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}l c c c c c } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Max} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
mpg & 32 & 20.091 & 6.027 & 10.400 & 33.900 \\ 
cyl & 32 & 6.188 & 1.786 & 4 & 8 \\ 
disp & 32 & 230.722 & 123.939 & 71.100 & 472.000 \\ 
hp & 32 & 146.688 & 68.563 & 52 & 335 \\ 
drat & 32 & 3.597 & 0.535 & 2.760 & 4.930 \\ 
wt & 32 & 3.217 & 0.978 & 1.513 & 5.424 \\ 
qsec & 32 & 17.849 & 1.787 & 14.500 & 22.900 \\ 
vs & 32 & 0.438 & 0.504 & 0 & 1 \\ 
am & 32 & 0.406 & 0.499 & 0 & 1 \\ 
gear & 32 & 3.688 & 0.738 & 3 & 5 \\ 
carb & 32 & 2.812 & 1.615 & 1 & 8 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\normalsize 
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `help("stargazer")`:

```
   float: a logical value that indicates whether the resulting table
          will be a floating table (set off, for instance, by
          ‘\begin{table}’ and ‘\end{table}’).
```

So,

```
> stargazer(mtcars, float = FALSE)

% Table created by stargazer v.5.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: Fri, May 11, 2018 - 06:43:39 PM
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Max} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
mpg & 32 & 20.091 & 6.027 & 10.400 & 33.900 \\ 
cyl & 32 & 6.188 & 1.786 & 4 & 8 \\ 
disp & 32 & 230.722 & 123.939 & 71.100 & 472.000 \\ 
hp & 32 & 146.688 & 68.563 & 52 & 335 \\ 
drat & 32 & 3.597 & 0.535 & 2.760 & 4.930 \\ 
wt & 32 & 3.217 & 0.978 & 1.513 & 5.424 \\ 
qsec & 32 & 17.849 & 1.787 & 14.500 & 22.900 \\ 
vs & 32 & 0.438 & 0.504 & 0 & 1 \\ 
am & 32 & 0.406 & 0.499 & 0 & 1 \\ 
gear & 32 & 3.688 & 0.738 & 3 & 5 \\ 
carb & 32 & 2.812 & 1.615 & 1 & 8 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}
```